# Where is the Google Apps Domain Verification link?

Tags: google-workspace

Where on earth is the Verification link in Google Apps?  Every time it seems like they change where it is.  When I initially log into my account, I can't verify it because I have to change the nameservers first and then verify.  The link was there before, now I can't find it.  Don't tell me its at the top on the Dashboard, b/c it's not.

Answer (score 1):

It just wasn't there.  I don't think a screen shot would have helped.  After another 45 min, From the dashboard, I had to click **settings**, Click **Email** under Services on the left, Click **Instructions on how to activate Email**, click **Change MX records**, Click **verify domain ownership**.

What a ridiculous process.

Answer (score 1):

Hi everyone who are trouble finding the domain verificaton link on google apps. Please visit the following link enter your email id@yourdomain name and then you will find the links on very first page in the top.It may not work for all countries but its working in India atleast.

http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/

Answer (score 0):

Get to the administration area. The URL should look something like `https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/example.com/Dashboard` where example.com is your domain.

Click the tab labeled "Setup" in the group along the top of the dashboard (**yes**).
The resulting screen will have a bunch of vertical tabs at left.
If it's not expanded already, activate the "Welcome" tab.
Under it is a "Verify domain ownership" item.

Comment: Ya, that's not right dude, sorry.

Comment: @picxelplay You're going to have to define "not right," then. I specifically walked through the process in my own account to write that, and have now checked it for three domains, including one that hasn't been migrated/merged with the generic Google accounts. Maybe you have some slightly different version of the dashboard, or whatever. A screenshot might show that up.